# bootstrap Carousel diseble dropdown panel in navbar

Tags: html, css, carousel

When I put bootstrap Carousel on my index page, dropdown panel is not falling after clicking in the navbar. If I remove Carousel then dropdown panel works properly
 HTML code for bootstrap Carousel is as follows

```
<script>
#myCarousel{
margin-top: 0%; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  }
}

.carousel-inner .item > img {
  -webkit-animation: zoom 20s;
  animation: zoom 20s;
}

</script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
 </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/sl1.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/sl2.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>
 </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

This an global example based on your code with code in action jsfiddle

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placekitten.com/640/360" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://baconmockup.com/640/360" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

#myCarousel{
margin-top: 0%; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  }
}

.carousel-inner .item > img {
  -webkit-animation: zoom 20s;
  animation: zoom 20s;
}
```

Code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/Mohcinbn/t3gz7r5k/